# Object Attributes in Java as Array or List Elements

Tags: java

Is there a way in Java to iterate through the attributes of an object? Just like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    private Object field_1;
    private Object field_2;
    ...
    private Object field_n;

    // methods here

}
```

where o.field(i) refers to o.field_i?

Comment: Why? What is the context in which you want to do this?

Comment: Well, it is, but not recommend as long as it is not absolutely neccessary... What about tell us what you need, maybe we find out, whats wrong with your design...?

Comment: For the sake of answering your question: no. Rethink why you want to do this.

Comment: I'm using the Apache Commons CSV (the writer). Basically I get a list of Objects (JSON actually, from RESTful endpoint, converted to Java Objects), and I want to write each objects properties by loop, instead of by hand (let's assume it's a flat JSON).

Comment: You can use reflection.

Comment: @MarounMaroun can you give an example?

Comment: @menorah84 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) you can find the best examples. Note that it's hard to get exactly what you want, Java has no dynamic variable naming, however, you can get similar solution.

Comment: I am very sure that the library you are using does not rely on you writing reflection code. Again: do not do this. It creates hard-to-understand code, couples internal details of a class to the outside world, creates poitentially very hard to trace bugs and so on.

Comment: you get JSON from a RESTful endpoint and use CSV to parse it? that sounds like quite the mismatch to me. Your question really could use these additional details, though

Comment: Both, JSON and CSV are generic structures without specific Java types involved. So your mistake is to use a library to generate concrete Java types in order to need Reflection to process these types generically. Instead, just use a parser that spits out a `List` of `Map` or a `List` of `List` or such alike instead of a framework that generates Java classes; after all, you want to convert a `String` to another `String`, nothing else…

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood you question but if you want to manipulate JSON and Java objects you should consider using library like [Genson](https://owlike.github.io/genson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

If you really want to inspect your class' attributes (which you should not really be considered because it is not really clean coding) you can consider reflection as indicated by Andremoniy

**EDIT :** 
I'm sorry, as Vogel612 said I'll explain. 
After reading the **post comments**, you seems to receive message on REST WebServices in JSON that is then converted to Java Object.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you want want to manipulate you Java object and obtain JSON or the other way round without coding everything by hand.

If it is what you need, you can consider the library I cited earlier and I would add Gson from Google. These libraies provide several method to convert automatically Java object to JSON and JSON to Java object without laborious conversion coding.

Comment: There hasn't been a mention of JSON anywhere in the question. While it actually is the real Problem OP is facing you might want to explain a little more and also refer to the comment done by OP to explain why you're not answering the "direct" question

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but it is not recommended, avoid at all cost if possible.

This code :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class JavaApplication24 {

    public Integer x;
    public Integer y;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        JavaApplication24 app = new JavaApplication24();
        app.x = 10;
        app.y = 20;

        for (Field f : app.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
            System.out.println(f.getType());
            System.out.println(f.toGenericString());
            System.out.println(f.get(app));
        }
    }
}
```

Have this output

```
x
class java.lang.Integer
public java.lang.Integer javaapplication24.JavaApplication24.x
10
y
class java.lang.Integer
public java.lang.Integer javaapplication24.JavaApplication24.y
20
```

Google reflection for more info.

Comment: Please consider explaining why OP should avoid using reflection at all cost. If OP knew about reflection, he would probably not have asked the question, so you have a great opportunity to teach him why it is in your oppinion something he should avoid.

Comment: @LionC - if I dont know what he is doing and what he needs, I cant give advice. Only the general ones and theres a full internet of them.

Comment: He actually explained a fair bit about why he wants to do that in the comments. And I am sure that you can explain why reflection is a bad thing in some words, even without more context.

Comment: “avoid at all cost” is a very strong phrase. I guess, once the cost of avoiding it exceed the costs imposed by the use of Reflection, a pragmatic programmer should decide to *not* avoid Reflection “at all cost”…

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Apache commons BeanUtils` to get all properties and their values.
Please refer `describe()` from `PropertyUtils` or `PropertyBeanUtils` class.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe(java.lang.Object)

E.g.

```
TestBean bean = new TestBean();
bean.setId(1);
bean.setName("test");
bean.setLastAccessed(new Date());
System.out.println(PropertyUtils.describe(bean));
```

Comment: this is not the "java" way it's the "apache" way. Recommending a Library (which will probably not do *exactly* what is wanted anyways) isn't helping here

Comment: I wasn't aware "java" way should exclude so called "apache" ways!!...also as OP wanted to iterate over the attributes of object and print them, the `describe()` method returns a map of all readable attributes which OP can iterate and print.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for *fields* which is *not* what `BeanUtils` will evaluate. If the “apache way” really is to use a third party library first and ask yourself whether, what the library actually does, matches your task afterwards, well then it’s really “not the Java way”…

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can via `reflection`. But it is not really efficient way for dealing with object's fields:

```
public static Object getFieldValue(SomeClass someClass, int i ) {
    try {
        Field declaredField = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("field_" + i);
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = declaredField.get(someClass);
        declaredField.setAccessible(false);
        return value;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider explaining what you mean by "not efficient". Im pretty sure you would not use reflection for yourself - by not explaining why, we potentially just teached someone to write very bad code.

Comment: Yes, but I would be happy to upvote the answer if it contained a bit more info about how to use or not to use the code :-) I just think that in the current form the answer is not very useful

Comment: If the access happens within the same class, there is no need to use `setAccessible(true)`. On the other hand, if the access happens outside the class, the implications of calling `setAccessible(true)` should be explained. By the way, calling `setAccessible(false)` right before the `Field` instance goes out of scope is obsolete.