# Hot to convert filled object into an Array of Strings

Tags: android, arrays, json

Currently I have this `object`:

```
CurrencyType(Stuff1=null, Stuff2=0.61952, Stuff3=1.2117, Stuff4=2.9687, Stuff51=0.95025, Stuf6=0.69852, Stuff7=4.9222, Stuff8=15.931, Stuff9=4.6196, Stuff10=0.55648, Stuff11=5.6577, Stuff12=4.6056, Stuff13=202.27, Stuff14=10732.0, Stuff15=2.5838, Stuff16=51.865, Stuff17=79.175, Stuff18=80.258, Stuff19=808.33, Stuff20=13.856)
```

Since I want to display this results in a `Recycler View` and the JSON does not give me an `Array` I need to split these values into an `Array`. Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Convert java objects to JSON and vice versa. https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Can you show an example using my code?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use reflection like in these answers:

- [Object Attributes in Java as Array or List Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645102/object-attributes-in-java-as-array-or-list-elements)
- [Getting a list of all fields in an object](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108222/getting-a-list-of-all-fields-in-an-object)

As they say in the answers, if you could avoid using reflection and try to have your array directly, don't hesitate (reflection raises performance issues).

Answer (score 0):

Convert Object to String(.toString())

```
    String datam="CurrencyType(Stuff1=null, Stuff2=0.61952, Stuff3=1.2117, Stuff4=2.9687, Stuff51=0.95025, Stuf6=0.69852, Stuff7=4.9222, Stuff8=15.931, Stuff9=4.6196, Stuff10=0.55648, Stuff11=5.6577, Stuff12=4.6056, Stuff13=202.27, Stuff14=10732.0, Stuff15=2.5838, Stuff16=51.865, Stuff17=79.175, Stuff18=80.258, Stuff19=808.33, Stuff20=13.856)";
    String[] arr_one=datam.replace("CurrencyType(","").replace(")","").split(",");

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr_one));
```

This is not perfect answer but it may help you